# Single columns from several rows into several columns in one record, but allow NULL in the rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, left-join, conditional-aggregation

I'm trying to combine single rows from multiple records into several columns in one record.

Say we have a database of people and they've all chosen 2 numbers. But, some people have only chosen 1 number and haven't submitted their 2nd number.

This is a simplified example, in my actual production database, it's scaled up to several of these 'numbers'.

From this example, person 3 hasn't chosen their 2nd number yet.

I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT ppl.*,
       cn1.chosen_num AS first_num,
       cn2.chosen_num AS second_num

  FROM people AS ppl
       LEFT JOIN
       chosenNumbers AS cn1
       LEFT JOIN
       chosenNumbers AS cn2

 WHERE ppl.numid = cn1.personid
   AND ppl.numid = cn2.personid
   
   AND cn1.type = 'first'
   AND cn2.type = 'second'
```

But it doesn't return any information on Person3, since they haven't chosen their second number yet. However, I want data on EVERYONE involved in this number guessing, but I want to be able to see the first and second numbers they've guessed.

Here is a dump of the sample database where I'm testing this.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE people (numid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO people VALUES(1,'Person1');
INSERT INTO people VALUES(2,'Person2');
INSERT INTO people VALUES(3,'Person3');
CREATE TABLE chosenNumbers (numid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, chosen_num INTEGER, type TEXT, personid INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(personid) REFERENCES people(numid));
INSERT INTO chosenNumbers VALUES(1,101,'first',1);
INSERT INTO chosenNumbers VALUES(2,102,'second',1);
INSERT INTO chosenNumbers VALUES(3,201,'first',2);
INSERT INTO chosenNumbers VALUES(4,202,'second',2);

-- Person 3 hasn't chosen their 2nd number yet..
-- But I want data on them, and the query above
-- doesn't work.
INSERT INTO chosenNumbers VALUES(5,301,'first',3);
COMMIT;
```

I'd also appreciate being told how I could scale this up to say, 3 numbers, or 4 numbers, or even more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.type = 'first' THEN c.chosen_num END) AS first_num,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.type = 'second' THEN c.chosen_num END) AS second_num
FROM people AS p LEFT JOIN chosenNumbers AS c
ON p.numid = c.personid
GROUP BY p.numid;
```

You can expand the code for more columns.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f90a909846bb0abcf1b7e16de4e3879e).